# Display <fb:loginbutton /> using xslt?

Tags: xml, facebook, fbml, xfbml

I'm trying to display an facebook login-button in my xslt-rendered site.

I'm putting

```
<fb:loginbutton></fb:login-button>
```

in the xslt but my page just renders

```
<login-button></login-button>
```

Why, and what can I do about it?

Comment: are you including the javascript that allows fbml to be inserted into pages??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asume loginbutton instead of login-button is a typo? Do you have a complete example?

When I have this xml:

```
<test>hi</test>
```

And this xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="test">
      <html>
         <body>
            <fb:login-button>
            test
            </fb:login-button>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I will get the following result:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <body>
    <fb:login-button>
      test
    </fb:login-button>
  </body>
</html>
```