# Using colon in attribute names in xsl transformations

Tags: xslt, addthis

```
<xsl:template name="AddThis">
        <div class="AddThis">
            <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
            <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" addthis:url="{be:GetFullBlogUrl(@Date, @Title)}" addthis:title="{@Title}" xmlns:addthis="http://www.addthis.com">
        <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:width="115"> </a>
                <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
                <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style addthis_nonzero"></a>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4f86b27a69737a92"></script>
            <!-- AddThis Button END -->
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
```

I need to add the fb:like:width="115" according to 
http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/125587-facebook-like-button-width#.UZyl2rVM_2P

but the xsl transformation of course can't figure that out, due to namespaces issues.
Any idea how to resolve it? Any option to just write out plain text.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to generate an attribute with 2 colons (a single colon `fb:` can be processed using a normal [xmlns alias prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216069/display-fbloginbutton-using-xslt)).

So instead, you can render a literal using `xsl:text` with `disable-output-escaping="yes"`, like so:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
  &lt;a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:width="115"&gt; &lt;/a&gt;
</xsl:text>
```

*Output:*

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:width="115">
```

Comment: I tried that, it resulted in the literal was printet as text on the page and not as an html tag.